# How to add images by clicking add icon many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following code user can click the icon to send multiple images by pressing ctrl. But it's not what I want. Instead, user can click the same icon many times and every time one image will be added. For example, in SO ask question page ,user can click the same "add image" icon many times to add multiple images. How to implement this?

```
<!-- This is not what I want. Each time one image will be added by clicking
     the same uploader, rather than by pressing ctrl.
 -->
<form action="storeArticle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple onchange="previewFile()"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: pot some more of your code..